# C# dictionary, need advice

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary

I want to write some sort of dictionary that would accept current time 
and return what user-define time period it is. As time-preiod I mean user-defined names for time period that are read from file. For example

8:00-9:00 - breakfast time
9:00-12:00 - work time
12:00-13:00 - lunch time

etc...

Currently I have a function is base on if-else if statements

```
// C# syntax omitted for simplicity
TimePeriod GetCurrentTimePeriod(DateTime t)
{
 if(t < 8.00)
 {
  return TimePeriod.Sleep;
 }
 else if(t < 9.00)
 { 
   ...
 }
}
```

I am not happy with this straight solution. I would prefer use some
sort of "dictionary" instead.

PS. Changed the word TimeZone to TimePeriod to avoid confusion with System.TimeZone class.

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend that you change the name you use for this concept. "Time zone" means something completely different, and you're just going to confuse whoever's reading your code/docs/whatever.

Comment: 2 Jon - Agree, actually in my code TimeZone is MarketState (Open, Closed etc) I try to use abstract cases for questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make those "periods of time" dynamically adjustable, I suggest building up a simple List of a record containing start time, end time, and description and simply query that list with LINQ. Since the number of items in that list is probably likely to be very small, linear search does the job and it isn't worth it to bother using binary search or more advanced data structures like segment trees:

```
class PeriodOfTime { 
   public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
   public DateTime EndTime {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;} // Use your own enum instead
}
// ... 
List<PeriodOfTime> periods = new List<PeriodOfTime>();

var timeToQuery = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var period = periods.FirstOrDefault(p => timeToQuery >= p.StartTime &&
                                         timeToQuery <= p.EndTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a couple of days ago. See the answer here for some ideas of how to proceed.

[A dictionary object that uses ranges of values for keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147505/a-dictionary-object-that-uses-ranges-of-values-for-keys)

Comment: All right, so it is interval trees. Will read about. Although
I agree with my task with quire a few items simple linear job will do the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good solution to me as written. Alternatively, you could design your own range-based map.

Answer (score 1):

You have not to use TimeZone class because you will get different time in specific time zone.

You can use this class for time converting, e.g.

```
TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
DateTime baseUTC = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
DateTime localTime = localZone.ToLocalTime(baseUTC);
TimeSpan localOffset = localZone.GetUtcOffset(localTime);
```

You may use simple check as answer to your question:

```
if (youTime >= 8.00 && youTime <= 9.00)
 return YourTypes.Breakfast; 
else if (youTime > 9.00 && youTime <= 12.00)
 return YourTypes.WorkTime;
else
 // etc.
```

Comment: The question is not about time zones at all. The use of the name "time zone" is totally confusing, as pointed out in comments by Jon.

Comment: I understand the question and try to explain this misunderstood in my answer.