# Interval container in C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, c#-4.0

Is there any interval container in C#?

I'm interested in that it combines overlapping internals, and that I can find intervals that are not in the container but are in a specific interval.

Comment: This is not a trivial question and does not deserve the down vote. In C++ there's a whole complex library only dealing with that https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html It's a shame there's no such a thing in C# only half baked forum posted implementations.

Comment: Do you want a dynamic container, that allows adding/removing elements all the time, or a static one that is populated once and then only searched?

Comment: Related: [A dictionary object that uses ranges of values for keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147505/a-dictionary-object-that-uses-ranges-of-values-for-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Someone by the name of Jani Giannoudis has posted a [.NET time period library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) on CodeProject that might fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a class like below:

```
public class Interval
{
   public long Start {get;set;}
   public long End{get;set;}

   public bool IsIn(Interval interval)
   {
      return Start >= interval.Start && End < interval.End;
   }

   public Interval Intersection(Interval interval)
   {
      if (interval == null)
        return false;

      if (IsIn(interval))
         return interval;
      if (interval.IsIn(this))
         return this;
      if ....
   }

   public Interval Union(Interval interval)
   {....}

   public bool IsIn(List<Interval> intervals)
   {
       return intrvals.Any(x=>IsIn(x));
   }

   public List<Interval> Intersect(List<Interval> intervals)
   {....}

   public List<Interval> Union(List<Interval> intervals)
   {....}
}
```

**Edit:** As @zmbq mentioned in comments, this can be done by struct, struct is more trivial way in this situations, I personally used class to simply deal with empty intervals (In fact if start - end >= 0, then interval is empty, instead of using predifined empty interval, I think we can set it to null. but I think this is syntax suger.

Comment: I think a struct is better for this purpose.

Comment: @zmbq, agree, but I used class to simply check null instead of empty intervals.

Comment: Oh, then a struct is *definitely* better for this purpose. That would be like making int a class, so you can use null for zeroes...

Answer (score 0):

No. You should be able to use LINQ to perform such check on simple array of pairs.

Comment: I think @Saeed Amiri's `Interval` example is going to make OP's code a lot clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) struct.

Comment: No I  need for example an interval of long's.