# I want to have data structure with (start,end) as key and then be able to search integer in whole data structure and get corresponding value

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'd like to have a

```
data structure with <Key, Value> where
  Key = (start, end), 
  Value = string
```

After which I should be able to search an integer optimally in the data structure and get corresponding value.

Example:

```
var lookup = new Something<(int, int), string>()
{
  {(1,100),"In 100s"},
  {(101,200),"In 100-200"},
}

var value1 = lookup[10]; //value1 = "In 100s"
var value2 = lookup[110]; //value2 = "In 100-200"
```

Could anyone suggest?

Comment: You need to give some example data, we need a [mcve].

Comment: And please try to make it so that the title and description match up a little better.  The title makes it sound like you are looking for something like a `Dictionary<List<object>, SomeType>`, but your question makes it look like the key to the dictionary is some type of 2-tuple (though I can't tell what types `start` and `end` (in your tuple) are)

Comment: Hi @Peeush Agarwal, Welcome to Stack Overflow, Have you try to implement one algorithm in particular? Have you investigate options? Please feel free to share any examples.

Comment: Do the `(start, end)` intervals overlap? If they do you could look at [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), otherwise you could use a `SortedDictionary` keyed on the start.

Comment: What is a `Something` here? Do you basically have a dictionary?

Comment: @Flydog57 Edited my question. Kindly suggest your answer.

Comment: @DavidG Something is what I'd like to know which I can use here.

Comment: @Lee intervals do not overlap. I'll have a look at SortedDictionary. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A dictionary object that uses ranges of values for keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147505/a-dictionary-object-that-uses-ranges-of-values-for-keys)

Comment: Roughly how many entries are in your collection: a handful, a couple of hundred, thousands, lots?  Since they don't overlap (and I'm assuming they are sorted), you just need to walk the collection, looking the `start` value; once you find one that's too big, you are once step too far.  But, that's O(N). I can't think of a way to beat O(N).  It looks like @devNull's suggestion may be the best.

Comment: If your intervals do not overlap, you can just store them in a binary search tree and then find a matching `start` in `O(log(N))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to use something like `lookup[10]` as you mentioned, you can create your own class that implements some sort of key/value data type. Which underlying data type you ultimately decide to use really depends on what your data looks like.

Here's a simple example of doing this while implementing a `Dictionary<>`:

```
public class RangeLookup : Dictionary<(int Min, int Max), string>
{
    public string this[int index] => this.Single(x => x.Key.Min <= index && index <= x.Key.Max).Value;
}
```

This allows you to define a custom [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) on top of the dictionary to encapsulate your range lookup. A usage of this class would look like:

```
var lookup = new RangeLookup
{
    { (1, 100), "In 100s" },
    { (101, 200), "In 101-200s" },
};

Console.WriteLine($"50: {lookup[50]}");
```

Which produces output as:

[image]

---

In terms of performance with this approach, the following is an example of some tests (using Win10 with an Intel i7-4770 CPU) retrieving a value from a dictionary with 10,000,000 records:

```
var lookup = new RangeLookup();

for (var i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++)
{
    var max = i * 100;
    var min = max - 99;
    lookup.Add((min, max), $"In {min}-{max}s");
}

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

stopwatch.Start();
Console.WriteLine($"50: {lookup[50]} (TimeToLookup: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds})");

stopwatch.Restart();
Console.WriteLine($"5,000: {lookup[5000]} (TimeToLookup: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds})");

stopwatch.Restart();
Console.WriteLine($"1,000,000,000: {lookup[1000000000]} (TimeToLookup: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds})");
```

Which gives the following results:

[image]

So unless you plan on working with more than tens of millions of records inside of this data set, an approach like this *should be* satisfactory in terms of performance.

Comment: While this works, I'm not a huge fan of the slight abuse of the indexer. It just feels a little janky to me.

Comment: @devNull That looks as what I wanted. I can live with the Indexer as they make the code simple and abstract the search. Thanks for sharing the performance timings as well.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have a `Dictionary<>` structure here, for example:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<(int, int), string>()
{
  {(1,100),"In 100s"},
  {(101,200),"In 100-200"},
};
```

You can use some basic Linq queries to search that container, for example:

```
var searchValue = 10;
var value1 = lookup.First(l => l.Key.Item1 <= searchValue && l.Key.Item2 >= searchValue);

searchValue = 110;
var value2 = lookup.First(l => l.Key.Item1 <= searchValue && l.Key.Item2 >= searchValue);
```

But as Lee suggested in the comments, you might get better performance using a `SortedDictionary`, your mileage may vary, which means you need to test the performance of both.